# Determining the number of edges on a spherical polyhedron given edge length and minimum inner diameter

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

This came from a silly hypothetical question. How many Seans would it take to contain the Earth inside a Spherical Polyhedron made of 3-Sean triangles*.

I think I have enough information to solve it:

- Our edge length is 1.98 meters (Sean is 6' 6" tall)
- Our minimum diameter is 12742000 meters (equatorial earth diameter)

But I'm not sure how to go about solving it.

**Not triangles technically, but you know what I mean*

EDIT: Here's what I'm thinking...

1. Surface area of the earth is ~510000000000000 m^2
2. Area of Sean-Triangle (1.98m Equilateral)  is 1.7m^2
3. Therefore ~300000000000000 Sean-Triangles

To use Euler's Polyhedron formula I would need to know the number of vertices, and then I could determine the number of edges.

Comment: You do not need to count the vertices.  Each edge is dhared by two facesxandcwach face is shared by three edges, forcing the numbef of edges to be exactly 3/2 times tge number of faces.  Thr vertices have to conform with that.  Assuming you choose five or six Seans per vertex exactly twelve of the vertices will have five.  In light of that you may want to consider instead a circumscribed icosahedron which leaves the Seans undistroted when you put them together.

Comment: Sean says he appreciates being undistorted. Because Seans are somewhat bendy, I was thinking a spherical polyhedron would be good, but the Earth is so big and Sean is so small, it doesn't matter at that scale.

Comment: What is a $3$-Sean triangle? Whatever it is, its area is measured in m${}^2$, not in m.